# react hooks closure issue

Tags: reactjs, closures, react-hooks

[image]

complete reproduce demo: https://github.com/leftstick/hooks-closure-issue

custom hooks as below:

```
import { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import { createModel } from "hox";

function testHooks() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    {
      id: "a",
      name: "hello"
    }
  ]);

  const removeUser = useCallback(
    user => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // async work here
          setUsers(users.filter(u => u.name !== user.name));
          resolve();
        }, 10);
      });
    },
    [users]
  );

  const addUser = useCallback(
    user => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // async work here
          // users here is not up-to-date
          setUsers([...users, user]);
          resolve();
        }, 10);
      });
    },
    [users]
  );

  //modify user = remove old-user + add new-user
  const modifyUser = useCallback(
    (oldUser, newUser) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        removeUser(oldUser)
          .then(() => {
            // addUser relies on latest users updated by removeUser
            // but due to closure issue, it refers to original value
            // what is the best approach to achieve the expected behivour?
            return addUser(newUser);
          })
          .then(resolve, reject);
      });
    },
    [users]
  );

  return {
    users,
    modifyUser
  };
}

export default createModel(testHooks);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as with `this.setState` for class-based components [functional version](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of setter saves the day

```
const removeUser = 
    user => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setUsers(users => users.filter(u => u.name !== user.name));
          resolve();
        }, 10);
      });
    }
;
```

Meanwhile chained updates looks suspicious. Having long enough chain if some step fails you may get into trouble trying to revert component to some consistent state. In general case I'd accumulate all data needed and then update component at once.